# How to differentiate Front page and other pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a front page (i.e `index.php`) with my own design. This page will contain

- header got from `<?php get_header(); ?>` *[has navigation bar code]*
- Then some content. Here I'm showing three thumbnails of posts. *[has slider, thumbnail posts etc]*
- And a footer from `<?php get_footer(); ?>`*[has footer links]*

The problem is, I see `index.php` loaded correctly as a front page. But when I navigate to other pages like About or Contact, the respective content from these pages is not showing up. Instead what getting loaded there is, same what Index page has. I don't want slider or thumbnail appearing on these pages.

So how to tell wp that, this is my front page, and this is my About page, don't load a slider and stuff on About page!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) to determine the home page. like you only want slider on the home page then edit your `header.php` file that consist the slider part and do something like this

```
if( is_front_page() ):
// Front Page stuff like slider and 
// whatever you want
endif;
```

Comment: You mean add this code to 'header.php'? my slider's code is in index.php

Comment: @SujitKulkarni **file that consist the slider part**

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
if( is_home() || is_front_page() ){
//your home page content
}
else{
//other pages

}
```

For more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

Hope its works..

Answer (score 1):

Make another template and set this template for your single pages. And then from backhand set it.

Comment: Ok I'll try this, and tell you what happens!

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a front-page.php file, Wordpress will use that instead of index.php (which you can use as a generic template from then on).